# Initialize a vector of vectors at a defined location - C++

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

Is it possible to initialize a vector of vectors of points at a specified location ?!

i.e.

```
std::vector<std::vector<CV::Point> vecvec;
std::vector<CV::Point> vecpnt;
CV::Point pnt;
pnt.x = px;
pnt.y = py;
vecpnt.push_back(pnt);
```

Then insert/push the ***vecpnt*** at/to the second row of the ***vecvec***. Assuming ***vecvec*** is not empty.

I tried:

```
vecvec[location].push_back(vecpnt); // Say _location_ is set to two.
```

I got no error but my code aborts right after compilation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does `vecvec` have at least three items in it?

Comment: Like `vecvec[1][1] = pnt;`?

Comment: no ! does it need three items to work ?!

Comment: @KerrekSB I can't really do that. I am trying to initialize it automatically every forty frames with mass centers.

Comment: If the number of vectors (rows) is known at compile time you might just be better off with `std::array<std::vector<CV:Point>, N>` where `N` is the fixed row-count. If not, you may also consider a `std::unordered_map<int,std::vector<CV::Point>>` which willl auto-add the index in question for you on first access through `operator []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resize your `vecvec` first. How many "locations" should it have? Let's say MaxLocations. Then you do

```
vecvec.resize(MaxLocations);
vecvec[location] = vecpnt;
```

If you don't know the size beforehand you can do something like this:

```
if(location >= vecvec.size())
{
    vecvec.resize(location+1);    
}
vecvec[location] = vecpnt;
```

Comment: I need to initialize it dynamically. I don't know what the MaxLocation will be!

Comment: @SJ You can resize as many times as you want, but before you can access `vecvec[x]` you will have to have a size of at least `x+1`. Where is `location` coming from?

Comment: @nijansen Thanks, you and Armen provided almost the same answer at the same time. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<T>` initializes with size 0, so `vecvec[2]` will most likely cause your crash. You can initialize `vecvec` with a certain size:

```
std::vector<std::vector<CV::Point> vecvec(10);
```

Comment: I need to initialize it dynamically. Will it be possible to change it later automatically if more rows are needed ?

Comment: @SJ Sure, as I commented in another answer, you can change it as many times as you want. Though it won't happen "automatically".